# Drupal calling a block programmatically, block title not displaying

Tags: drupal, drupal-blocks

I tried calling a block programmatically but it's not displaying the block title.
I added a block from the "add block" page. It has an id of 53.

I have this code in my page.tpl.php or node.tpl.php:

```
<?php  
$blockTest = (object) module_invoke('block', 'block', 'view', 53);
print theme('block', $blockTest);
?>
```

It does show the contents (body) of the block, but not the block title (subject).
Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug in Drupal core, at least in my reading of http://drupal.org/node/162899 and a potentially related issue at http://drupal.org/node/521668 The first one has a proposed patch, but it's a bit outdated, and will cause the update script to break. You can change the function in update.php after applying the patch to a number higher than what your current version is, but that might be a lot to ask. Even then, I couldn't get it to work.

Adding a cross-reference to your comment at http://drupal.org/node/26502#comment-3781716 which asks the same question.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the [block_load()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.module/function/block_load/7) function, it might help you.